# how can I make sure my progam is working successfully in kernel mode?

Tags: c++, c, kernel, kernel-mode

how can I make sure my program is working successfully in kernel mode or level in driver programming?

And how I can use this program if there is any program need to use?

Answer (score 2):

Analyze it with a kernel debugger. Search for WinDbg (on Windows) or KDB (on Linux).

Comment: Actually, the Windows kernel debugger is also called `kdb`. `windbg` is the usermode debugger.

Comment: Yeah, that's right, but actually WinDbg is a front-end to KDB (kernel mode) or CDB (user mode). It's the swiss knife for windows debugging :)